# How to return a String from java to javascript in spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I have this part of code in javascript

```
    function showHistory(taskId){               
        alert(historyManager.showHist(taskId));
    }
```

and I vave this method in HistoryManager.java

```
public String showHist(int taskId, HttpSession session) {
    String str=historyManager.listTasks(taskId);
    System.out.println(str);
    return(str);        
}
```

I need to get string from java to javascript. System.out.orintln(str); display result correctly but this string is not returned to javascript. 
Alert function display undefined.

Comment: If it is a controller method, you can add it as a model.addAttribute and from JSP you can pass it to your javascript.

Comment: you  can simple use @ResponceBody annotation over the method or as return type.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know for what kind of request your asking this, Whether is this the HTTP Request of Ajax Call ?

This is the one way of getting it value in jsp.

Change the code like this,

```
public String showHist(int taskId, HttpSession session, Map<String, Object> map) {
    String str=historyManager.listTasks(taskId);
    System.out.println(str);
    map.put("str",str)
    return("viewpage.jsp");        
}
```

in the javascript get it like this,

```
var taskId = '${str}';
```

If it is Ajax call

add `@ResponseBody` annotation in your method like this,

```
public @ResponseBody String showHist(int taskId, HttpSession session, Map<String, Object> map) {
        String str=historyManager.listTasks(taskId);
        System.out.println(str);
        map.put("str",str)
        return(str);        
    }
```

Comment: -1 as too speculative, OP never mentioned JSP and looks like their understanding is that JS code can connect directly to Spring beans so this answer is not going to help without explaining how client-server communication is done.